# Trouble with if in python

Tags: python, if-statement

Hey just starting to learn python and got some problems already
I made a code with an if statement It should work but it isn't working
can someone fix it and tell me what I did wrong?

```
x= raw_input("Enter your name: ")
y= raw_input("Enter your grade: ")
print(y)
if y>=50 and y<=100:
    print("Good input")
else:
     print ("Invaild input")
```

It always prints Invalid input 
thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`raw_input()` returns a string but you are comparing `x` and `y` with integers.

Turn `y` into a integer before comparing:

```
y = int(y)
if y >= 50 and y <= 100:
```

You can simplify your comparison a little with chaining, letting you inline the `int()` call:

```
if 50 <= int(y) <= 100:
```

Answer (score 5):

You have to convert the input to an integer by putting it in [`int`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#int):

```
x= raw_input("Enter your name: ")
################
y= int(raw_input("Enter your grade: "))
################
print(y)
if y>=50 and y<=100:
    print("Good input")
else:
    print ("Invaild input")
```

Remember that `raw_input` always returns a string.  So, in your if-statement, you are comparing a string with integers.  That is why it doesn't work.

Actually, whenever I need to print one message or another, I like to put it on one line (unless of course the messages are long):

```
print("Good input" if 50 <= y <= 100 else "Invaild input")
```

Making a whole if-else block seems a little overkill here.

Answer (score 1):

`raw_input()` function waits for user to input data , it is similar to `scanf()` function in C. But the data which you input is stored as string, so we need to convert into our specified form like integer, float etc

Ex: `y = raw_input("Enter data");`

to convert the data into integer we need to use

```
y = int(y)
```

in the similar way we can convert into different datatypes

Answer (score 0):

You have convert it to an `int`. `raw_input` gives you a string.

```
x= raw_input("Enter your name: ")
y= raw_input("Enter your grade: ")
print(y)
if 50 <= int(y) <= 100:
    print("Good input")
else:
     print ("Invaild input")
```

But what if the user does not enter a number, then you need to add a Try-Except block:

```
x = raw_input("Enter your name: ")
y = raw_input("Enter your grade: ")
print(y)

try:
    if 50 <= int(y) <= 100:
        print("Good input")
    else:
        print ("Invaild input")
except ValueError:
    print "You did not enter a number for your grade"
```

Comment: ?  If you are going to do that, you need to remove the `int` around `raw_input`.